# XPath to match a range of values

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file, with each "row" element containing a postal code range.  For this case, we use the 1st 3 characters of the postal (the FSA).

Is there a way to query the XML in XPath to find a matching "row" that contains the postal code?

```
<xml>
    <row note='Matches L3R' postalmin='L3P' postalmax='L3T' zone='ZONE 11'/>
    <row note='Matches G1J' postalmin='G1A' postalmax='G3K' zone='ZONE 10'/>
</xml>
```

For example, if I was searching for the zone for postal FSA 'L3R' it would return the Zone 11 row, or if searching for 'G1J' it would return ZONE 10.

In SQL terms it's something like this

```
declare @fsa as varchar(3) = 'G1J'

select * from zone 
where postalmin <= @fsa and postalmax >= @fsa
```

In XPath I'm trying something like this with just the postalmin to start, but it doesn't match anything.

```
//row[@postalmin <= L3R]
```

I'm coding this in C# .NET, so that limits me to XPath 1.0 (ugh)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'm coding this in C# .NET, so that limits me to XPath 1.0" You're aware that third-party libraries exist?

Answer (score 1):

XPath 1.0 has no capability to compare strings (except for equality). In XSLT 1.0 you can work around this using `xsl:sort`, but not in pure XPath.

You could consider a third-party XPath library such as Saxon (my company's product), or you could consider using LinQ.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay, I'll have a look at Saxon, I wish it was part of .NET, Microsoft could really use your help!

Comment: Microsoft have always preferred developing their own technologies rather than implementing standards from third parties.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in this case using the `translate` function to turn FSA codes into numbers

FSA letters go from A to Y so a double translation is needed. First the last letter then the first.
Translating the static needle:

```
translate(translate("G1J","MNPRSTVXY","12345678"), "ABCEGHJKL", "123456789")
```

Result

```
517
```

Doing the same for the haystack values

```
translate(translate("G1A","MNPRSTVXY","12345678"), "ABCEGHJKL", "123456789")
511
translate(translate("G1K","MNPRSTVXY","12345678"), "ABCEGHJKL", "123456789")
518
```

Full xpath would be

```
//row[translate(translate("G1J","MNPRSTVXY","12345678"), "ABCEGHJKL", "123456789") >= translate(translate(@postalmin,"MNPRSTVXY","12345678"), "ABCEGHJKL", "123456789") and translate(translate("G1J","MNPRSTVXY","12345678"), "ABCEGHJKL", "123456789") <= translate(translate(@postalmax,"MNPRSTVXY","12345678"), "ABCEGHJKL", "123456789")]
```

which returns

```
<row note="Matches G1J" postalmin="G1A" postalmax="G3K" zone="ZONE 10"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's clever solution, even if it's not very pretty.

Comment: It's not pretty indeed :-) but works lol